# How to make a program read another file and also add to it in Python

Tags: python

Alright, I have a little quiz that I made, and I want to add high scores to it. I just called the first one Maths Test.py which works well, though I want to be able to save high scores in a seperate file and also add stuff to it after someone has completed it. I'd just like to know how to load another file into my original quiz, and than add extra info to it. Thanks!

Comment: Show us some code to exemplify what you are trying to accomplish, it's easier for us to help you that way.

Answer (score 0):

to save information you can write to a file:

do something like this:

```
with open('highscores.txt','w') as f:
    f.write() #stuff you want to write to the file
```

to read the file use `file.read()`

this will write whatever information you give to `file.write()` to a txt file then save it you can then open it and read the information later this is called file In and Out or I/O

Comment: make sure you already have a file named `"highscores.txt"` or whatever name you want

Comment: I got half of it to work, I'll complete the rest tomorrow, it's kinda late.. haha

Comment: By the way, You don't _actually_ need a pre-made file if you open it in writing mode, `open('name.anything', 'w')` will automatically create a file called `'name.anything'`. Only when you're reading do you need to make sure the file already exists in that directory.

Comment: And Beroe how do I do that? I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: I ran into a little bit of a problem here, for some reason, when I try to read the file, it says it is unreadable, but I was able to write something to it. If you could help, it would be nice.